# How do I use just one category' posts on my home page?

Tags: categories

I have mainly protected categories, but I have one open category, how can I set it up so I load only the open catgeory posts to show on my home page

Comment: WE NEED MOAR INFORMATIONZ - how are you protecting categories? A plugin? Which one? Are you using a public theme or your own?

Comment: I'm using the UAM to protect the categories and the theme is Third Style 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should about do it for you, add args as needed

```
$args = array(
    //basic post data
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    //category
    'category_name'  => 'your-cat-slug'
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Docs: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thank you, does this go in the loop.php file?

Comment: Really depends on your setup...loop.php isn't even a default file, so you'll have to figure that out on your own, but I would guess it does. [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) documentation should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to filter the query on the home page instead of adding another one with WP_Query

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_query' );
function my_home_query( $query ) {
 if( $query->is_home ) {
       $query->set( 'cat', $cat_id );
   }
     return $query;
}
```